# Formula Validating one field against another

Tags: crystal-reports

In Crystal, I have a report that checks for information on vehicles in an auto shop. The two fields I'm working with are "Inspection" (which can be any number of inspection types) and "Next Inspection Date." Not every vehicle will have an inspection on it's record, and that's fine. In the cases where there is no inspection, it's only natural that there is no "next inspection date" listed. However, I want to build a formula that will flag instances where an inspection type has been assigned but no next inspection date has been assigned. If there is an assigned inspection type AND a next inspection date in the fields, then I just want it to return the value from the "Next Inspection Date" field.

I've been working with IF/THEN/ELSE and trying to incorporate some isnull operators, but I just can't seem to get the syntax correct.

Here's my formula currently (that doesn't work):
if isnull {DATE_NEXT_SCHEDULED} AND {INSPECTION.TYPE} > "" then "Date Needed" else {DATE_NEXT_SCHEDULED}.

If I could somehow get the "Date Needed" String to also be highlighted, that would be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. The following formula got me what I needed:

if isnull({DATE_NEXT_SCHEDULED}) AND {INSPECTION.TYPE} > "" then "Date Needed" else totext({DATE_NEXT_SCHEDULED})